# Copy data from one table to another and change id

Tags: sql

I want to copy one row from one table to another table. But in the process I want change value of id. For example to 20. How to do it?

I have this code

```
INSERT INTO work_done
SELECT * FROM work_todo
WHERE id = 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try somethink like tis

```
INSERT INTO work_done
          ( id
          , col2
           ...
          )
     SELECT 20
          , col2
           ...
      FROM work_todo WHERE id = 10
```

Comment: Quite possibly, the values `10` and `20` are in fact **numerical** values and stored in a column of numerical type - so then they should **not** be put in double quotes in your query...

Comment: `"20"` is an **identifier** (e.g. a column name) in SQL. I doubt there is a column named `"20"` in the work table

Comment: answer updated :)

Comment: i just tested my query, this work well

Comment: oh, I have used quotation marks in brackets.. tx :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
 into work_done
 from work_todo
where id = 10;

update work_done a
   set a.id = 20;
```

OR

```
 select case id
            when id = 10
              then id = 20
     into work_done
     from work_todo
    where id = 10;
```